# Error in uploading photo in laravel with vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, upload, vue-component

I'm making a single page application using laravel and vuejs with vue-router. I'm using the `api.php` routes for my http requests. And whenever I save a data in my `news` table with image, it shows me an error. What do I need to do with this? 
[image]
NewsController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\News;
class NewsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return News::latest()->paginate(10);
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required|string|max:191|unique:news',
            'subtitle' => 'required|string|max:191',
            'body' => 'required|string',
            'image' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg,PNG|max:2048',
        ]);


        $news = new News;
        $news->title = $request->title;
        $news->subtitle = $request->subtitle;
        $news->body = $request->body;
        if ($request->hasFile('image')){
            //Add new photo
                $image = $request->file('image');
                $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $location = public_path('img/news/' . $filename);
                \Image::make($image)->resize(300,300)->save($location);

                $oldFilename = $news->image;
            //Update DB
                $news->image = $filename;
             //Delete the old photo
                // Storage::delete($oldFilename);
        }

        $news->save();
    }
}
```

News.vue

```
<!-- Vform -->
                                  <form @submit.prevent="createNews()">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>News Title</label>
                                    <input
                                    v-model="form.title"
                                    type="text" name="title"
                                    placeholder="Title"
                                    class="form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('title') }">
                                    <has-error :form="form" field="title"></has-error>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Subtitle</label>
                                    <input
                                    v-model="form.subtitle"
                                    type="text"
                                    name="subtitle"
                                    placeholder="Subtitle"
                                    class="form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('subtitle') }">
                                    <has-error :form="form" field="subtitle"></has-error>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>News Content</label>
                                    <textarea
                                    v-model="form.body"
                                    type="text"
                                    name="body"
                                    placeholder="News Content"
                                    class="form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('body') }">
                                    </textarea>
                                    <has-error :form="form" field="body"></has-error>
                                    </div>


                                    <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Picture</label>
                                    <input type="file" id="image"
                                    class="form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('image') }">
                                    <has-error :form="form" field="image"></has-error>
                                    </div>


                        <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                         <!-- <button  v-show="editmode" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button> -->
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Create</button>
                         </div>
                        </form>
                        <!-- vform -->

<script>
    export default {
        data(){
            return{
                news: {},
                form: new Form({
                    id:"",
                    title: "",
                    subtitle:"",
                    body:"",
                    image:"",
                    postedby:""
                })
            }
        },

        methods: {
            loadNews(){
                axios.get('api/news')
                    .then(({data}) => (this.news = data))
            },
            createNews(){
                this.$Progress.start()
                this.form.post("api/news")
                    .then(()=>{
                         $("#addNews").modal("hide")
                         $(".modal-backdrop").remove()
                        swal.fire("Created!", "", "success")
                    })
                this.$Progress.finish()
            },
        },

        created() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
            this.loadNews()
        }
    }
</script>
```

api.php

```
Route::apiResource('news', 'API\NewsController');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you checked that your are using a multipart/form-data encoding ?

Edit:
https://github.com/cretueusebiu/vform/blob/master/example/upload.html

Comment: im just using a package called `vform` and i followed the instructions there, and I can submit all data except for the image

Comment: Don't hesitate to look on github issues ;) https://github.com/cretueusebiu/vform/issues/12

Here someone had the same problem. You need to transform your object to a FormData.
https://github.com/cretueusebiu/vform/blob/master/example/upload.html

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Comment: so there is nothing wrong with my controller sir? I find it difficult to understand but ill try to understand it

Comment: I don't know if your controller is ok. If i were you, i will first check if my form is right encoded. You can check that using your developer tool. Open it, use "Network" tab, then send your form. You should see your request sent. Click on it then click on "Headers". Then scroll down, you should see your request data. It should be named as "FormData". Click on "view source". You should see ------WebKitFormBoundary etc. Also, it will inform you of the Content-Type used. Then if it's ok, you can check your controller.

Comment: nothing changes in my `image` field whenever I put some file in it. But when I input some text in the title in the form, the `title` in the form data changes immediately sir.

Comment: Did you linked your input ? like you did with your textarea ;) ?

Comment: whenever I put `v-model = form.photo` in my input file sir it gets me an error `v-model doesnt support fille input type`

Comment: Look at the example provided by your lib. It is using the "change" event.

Comment: It assign `e.target.files[0]` to his `form.file` property.

Comment: now the form `image` field changed to the image file name sir but when I submit the form it  gets me the error I provided in the screenshot. Any idea whats wrong with this?

Comment: Great ! So now, read again our discussion. `FormData` + `developer tool`

Comment: I cant figure it out its very hard for me. I just used my old code in uploading image and now it wont work with vue?

Comment: You need to `transform` your `Form` like in the example. l45-56: https://github.com/cretueusebiu/vform/blob/master/example/upload.html because you need to use FormData. In the example, they are using a lib called 'object-to-formdata'. Which is simply turn an object to a FormData object. But i recommend you to do it without this lib. You need to learn how to use FormData.

Answer (score 0):

> put this code in your Vue file

```
 <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <input
                    type="file"
                    @change="updateImage"
                    class="form-input"
                    :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('image') }"
                    id="image"
                    name="image"
                  />
                  <has-error :form="form" field="image"></has-error>
                </div>

<script>
    export default {
        data(){
            return{
                news: {},
                form: new Form({
                    id:"",
                    title: "",
                    subtitle:"",
                    body:"",
                    image:"",
                    postedby:""
                })
            }
        },

        methods: {
updateImage(e) {
      let file = e.target.files[0];
      console.log(file);
      let reader = new FileReader();
      if (file["size"] < 2111775) {
        reader.onloadend = file => {
          this.form.image= reader.result;
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      } else {
        swal.fire({
          type: "error!",
          title: "Oops...",
          text: "Your are uploading a large File "
        });

        // return ["warning", "file size"];
        Fire.$emit("refreshPage");
      }
    },
            loadNews(){
                axios.get('api/news')
                    .then(({data}) => (this.news = data))
            },
            createNews(){
                this.$Progress.start()
                this.form.post("api/news")
                    .then(()=>{
                         $("#addNews").modal("hide")
                         $(".modal-backdrop").remove()
                        swal.fire("Created!", "", "success")
                    })
                this.$Progress.finish()
            },
        },

        created() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
            this.loadNews()
        }
    }
</script>
```

**your controller code is**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\News;
class NewsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return News::latest()->paginate(10);
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required|string|max:191|unique:news',
            'subtitle' => 'required|string|max:191',
            'body' => 'required|string',
            'image' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg,PNG|max:2048',
        ]);


        $news = new News;
        $news->title = $request->title;
        $news->subtitle = $request->subtitle;
        $news->body = $request->body;
        if ($request->hasFile('image')){
$name = time().'.'.explode('/',explode(':',substr($request->image,0,strpos($request->image,';')))[1])[1];
                    \Image::make($request->image)->save(public_path('img/news/').$name);


            //Update DB
                $news->image = $name ;

        }

        $news->save();
    }
}
```

**If it worked let me know I will provide code for update**